# WhyWaitForControlExist() returning false when querying for the second time on the same UI control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am facing a weird behavior with WaitForControlExist() function of Coded UI. When querying for the second time, the value is returning false even though the control exist.. Is this the expected behavior of Coded UI? My Program looks something similar like below..

```
//A sample program that Checks for Run window when "Windows + R" key is pressed

public void TestFunction()
{
   bool isExists = false;

   #region Variable Declarations

   UIMap uiMap = new UIMap();

   WinWindow uIRunWindow = uiMap.UIRunWindow;
   WinComboBox uIOpenComboBox = uiMap.UIRunWindow.UIItemWindow.UIOpenComboBox;
   WinButton uICancelButton = uiMap.UIRunWindow.UICancelWindow.UICancelButton;

   #endregion

   //1st Run

   Keyboard.SendKeys("R", ModifierKeys.Windows);
   isExists = uIRunWindow.WaitForControlExist(7000);
   Console.WriteLine("Is Run Window Appears :: " + isExists); 
   Mouse.Click(uICancelButton);
   Playback.Wait(2000);
   isExists = uIRunWindow.WaitForControlNotExist(7000);
   Console.WriteLine("Is Run Window Closes :: " + isExists);

   //2nd Run 

   Keyboard.SendKeys("R", ModifierKeys.Windows);
   isExists = uIRunWindow.WaitForControlExist(7000);
   Console.WriteLine("Run Window Appears :: " + isExists); 
   Mouse.Click(uICancelButton);
   Playback.Wait(2000);
   isExists = uIRunWindow.WaitForControlNotExist(7000);
   Console.WriteLine("Is Run Window Closes :: " + isExists);

}
```

In the above program, during the 2nd run event though Run window exists the value is returned as false.

The work around I came across is either to use 2 different objects for 1st and 2nd run, or to reinitialize the UIMap object as shown [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/vsautotest/thread/6cf1ab30-af1f-4f20-934f-7c574c1565cb)

Please help me if there is any other solution or best practice in this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search results and the trees created by MSAA/UIAutomation are cached. In the [search configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd580315) for the control you can turn AlwaysSearch on which should solve the problem, without needing to recreate the control.

Comment: Yeah.. But some times it is taking lot of time.. Also when used wild cards for a window title, this one is failing.. Also when trying to find any of the child controls of such window, where AlwaysSearch is set it is taking lot of time..

Comment: @satya Your UIMap is a partial class, in the `UIMap.cs` (not `UIMap.Designer.cs`) you can create custom code without being overwritten when you have recorded an action again. You can create an own method in here with customized Search Properties. There you can decide if you want to AlwaysSearch or not per occurence that the control is used. Also choosing your wild cards and recognition properties wisely can reduce the search time significantly.

Comment: Most search properties can be set in the UIMap XML file if you are using the editor in feature pack 2 (and you should be). I think satya's problem is more with the fact AlwaysSearch makes actions very slow because searching the UIAutomation/MSAA tree is computationally expensive.

Comment: @satya Something else to consider with slow results and always search is that wildcards don't kick in until at least the 3rd pass. You will see a fair bit of performance improvement if you can create exact match window titles and control names. It might also fix the problem with inner controls not being recognized.

Comment: @stoj Do you have a source that is explaining how AlwaysSearch, wildcards etc. exactly work in combination with passes and matches? I am very interested, because sometimes tests can be a bit slow.  100 times 6 seconds less waiting is another 10 minutes saved.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos I can't seem to find the reference but as I remember the first pass in the search phase is for an exact match in non-minimized windows followed by an exact match in minimized. The third pass looks for approximately correct control, ones with approximately correct names, window titles and hierarchy. The third pass seems to be very computationally expensive likely because of the sheer number of possible combinations. There is an algo that decides when a control is close enough to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, after the window got closed, the uIRunWindow reference is "spent" and needs to be re-initialized.

The entirely sane approach to running the test more than once is to use a for() loop instead of repeating the same statements.  Start the loop before the uiMap assignment so you get a fresh map.

```
for (int test = 0; test < 2; ++test) {
    UIMap uiMap = new UIMap();
    // etc..
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. What exactly it mean by the reference is "Spent"? Is Coded UI does not dynamically evaluate for the control existence? It is not the same 'steps' running each time.. The code is to simplify the case..

Comment: Refreshing the uimap would work indeed, but it is cleaner to make it `null` by `UIMap uiMap = null;`. The getter for `UIMap` will set uiMap with a fresh uimap whenever it is needed.